# ubuntu kvm disk io slowdown after some tyme

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, io

Host system:

```
Ubuntu Server x64 12.04 
mdadm raid 1 (/dev/sda /dev/sdb)
no lvm
dd bs=1M count=256 if=/dev/zero of=filename conv=fdatasync
avarage ~ 40 MB/s

NCQ on disks is disabled
WriteCache is disables
```

Guest system:

```
Ubuntu server i386 12.04
with lvm2 /10Gb /200Gb /200Gb disks all on lv-root (LV)
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/vda5
  VG Name               root-vg
  PV Size               9.76 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              2498
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          2498

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/vdb
  VG Name               root-vg
  PV Size               195.31 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              49999
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          49999

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/vdc
  VG Name               root-vg
  PV Size               195.31 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              49999
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          49999

 dd bs=1M count=256 if=/dev/zero of=filename conv=fdatasync
    avarage ~ 30 MB/s
all disks in guest are RAWformat /VirtioBUS / No cache / IOmode=native
```

after some time write speed falls to 1 MB/s , but host system is not have loaded and dd test shows same 30-40 MB/s , cpu usage 10% . Guest reboot helps for a while. There is no errors/ faults / no mdadm rebuild or resync.

Have no idea where is a problem or where to dig.

---

Looks like this helps on guest: sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

---

Similar problem [On a system with 64GB mem the Linux Buffer run full while copying with dd to dev null and io stops till manual drop_caches](https://serverfault.com/questions/594488/on-a-system-with-64gb-mem-the-linux-buffer-run-full-while-copying-with-dd-to-dev/692624#692624)

Comment: I am not sure whether dd is a useful tool to benchmark disk performance. A better tool to use is bonnie++. Note that when running this test the amount of data you're working with should be larger than the amount of RAM because otherwise things like caching can mess up the results.

Comment: First you're using Ubuntu. Second you turned off NCQ (or you just don't have it because your disks are very low quality).

Comment: @Michael Hampton, I do not understand why using Ubuntu is making a difference?

Comment: Host system uses software raid md. raid level 1: NCQ should be off, write cache should be off.  About "benchmark disk performance" -- i dont benchmark it, it's spead about 20-30 MB/s on writting -- is OK to me. but some time later it drops to very low level, it is not possible to work with write speed max 1 MB/s  at server. Why this happens - i dont know.

Answer (score 0):

I think what happens is that the initial performance of 30-40 MB/s is because of linux kernel's caching (and any other caching that may be going on on a hardware level). Once that caching has been "used up" actual disk access starts to kick in and performance drops.

In addition in order for **dd** to have better performance set the ***bs=*** argument to a reasonably large size. Personally I like to set it to about 1/3-1/2 of available ram. Your setting of 1M is sub optimal and is the main reason  for the low performance numbers. But even with optimal ***bs=*** setting you would see a performance drop at some point as explained above.

Comment: dd bs=1024M count=1 if=/dev/zero of=filename conv=fdatasync
~ 20 MB/s #
dd bs=128M count=8 if=/dev/zero of=filename conv=fdatasync
~ 22 MB/s #
avarage RAM used 2  of total 16 GB ##

10 MB/s is slow, but i've got 1 MB/s after some  time. thats looks like bug maybe, system isnt busy .

Comment: Look likes this helps. 
sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches